# NextJs router seems very slow

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next-router

The problem is about that is taking long time to response another route. It seems next router's error and it can cause by this ("getServerSideProps"). How can I change with this code to another or did I need to change react router instead? This is index which used ("getServerSideProps") -

```
import axios from 'axios';

import VideoCard from '../components/VideoCard';
import { BASE_URL } from '../utils';
import { Video } from '../types';
import NoResults from '../components/NoResults';

interface IProps {
  videos: Video[];
}

const Home = ({ videos }: IProps) => {
  return (
    <div className='flex flex-col gap-10 videos h-full'>
      {videos.length 
        ? videos?.map((video: Video) => (
          <VideoCard post={video} isShowingOnHome key={video._id} />
        )) 
        : <NoResults text={`No Videos`} />}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Home;

export const getServerSideProps = async ({
  query: { topic },
}: {
  query: { topic: string };
}) => {
  let response = await axios.get(`${BASE_URL}/api/post`);

  if(topic) {
    response = await axios.get(`${BASE_URL}/api/discover/${topic}`);
  }
  
  return {
    props: { videos: response.data },
  };
};
```

This is from another code with that used next router

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { NextPage } from 'next';
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
import Link from 'next/link';
import { AiFillHome, AiOutlineMenu } from 'react-icons/ai';
import { ImCancelCircle } from 'react-icons/im';

import SuggestedAccounts from './SuggestedAccounts';
import Discover from './Discover';
import Footer from './Footer';
import useAuthStore from '../store/authStore';
const Sidebar: NextPage = () => {
  const [showSidebar, setShowSidebar] = useState<Boolean>(true);
  const { pathname } = useRouter();
  const { fetchAllUsers, allUsers }: any = useAuthStore();

  const activeLink = 'flex items-center gap-3 hover:bg-primary p-3 justify-center xl:justify-start cursor-pointer font-semibold text-[#F51997] rounded';

  const normalLink = 'flex items-center gap-3 hover:bg-primary p-3 justify-center xl:justify-start cursor-pointer font-semibold rounded';

  return (
    <div>
      <div
        className='block xl:hidden m-2 ml-4 mt-3 text-xl'
        onClick={() => setShowSidebar(!showSidebar)}
      >
        {showSidebar ? <ImCancelCircle /> : <AiOutlineMenu />}
      </div>
      {showSidebar && (
        <div className='xl:w-400 w-20 flex flex-col justify-start mb-10 border-r-2 border-gray-100 xl:border-0 p-3 '>
          <div className='xl:border-b-2 border-gray-200 xl:pb-4'>
            <Link href='/'>
              <div className={pathname === '/' ? activeLink : normalLink}>
                <p className='text-2xl'>
                  <AiFillHome />
                </p>
                <span className='capitalize text-xl hidden xl:block'>
                  For You
                </span>
              </div>
            </Link>
          </div>
          
          <Discover />
          <SuggestedAccounts
            fetchAllUsers={fetchAllUsers}
            allUsers={allUsers}
          />
          <Footer />
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Sidebar;
```

Comment: how long does it takes to load and show when you try to fetch the data from API endpoint?